# How to root a rare Android device?

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop

I have with me a Sharp RoBoHoN (SR-01M-W), it is an android device only sold in Asia, and there are very limited information about it on the internet and it is very hard to find outside of Japan, so I have been trying to learn as much as I can about how it works.

I have already decompiled a few of the system apps and learned some interesting things about it, but some of the things I want to do next will require root (swapping out systems apps, installing Google play store, doing a NANDroid backup, etc).

So how can I gain a root shell?

- I don't want to change anything on the device permanently / make sure anything I do is reversible, if root is gone after a restart/factory reset, that would be even better.
- I don't have the factory image.
- I am able to do a factory reset, but I don't know how to get into fastboot/recovery (It doesn't even have volume buttons).
- I have tried the DirtyCow exploit, which is able to write to run-as but it couldn't set my uid
- I know there are a few "one click root" apps out there, but they don't seems trust worthy and I want to do everything manually if possible to make sure I am not bricking it.
- It runs Android 5.0.2

Comment: First things first, you must have factory firmware image and enough information to flash it through fastboot or Download Mode, in case things go wrong. Custom recovery will get things more easy for you. Did you check `adb shell`? Might be your device has a `userdebug` or `eng` build of ROM and you already have a root shell. And don't go for one click solutions unless you are ready for worst consequences, they can do more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

Gaining root access could potentially lead to a reverse engineering of the device to locate an exploit and/or execute an exploit that could compromise the integrity of the system..

My concerns with this are SERIOUS !

Your specific device has many Physical Capabilities being a robot fitted with a projector.

Some famous hacks in the past have targeted people in a physical way, specifically I'm referring to a hack done on a Epilepsy foundation website that caused people visiting the site to have epileptic fits.

If someone was to gain access to your device they could potentially cause harm, Real Physical Harm using the robot to perform physical actions that could directly or indirectly cause physical harm.

- Showing flashing light's from the projector to cause epileptic fits !
- Walking around and causing dangerous situations like standing at the top of stairs.
- Showing disturbing or hypnotic video using the projector.

The list goes on...

Please for the sake of your health, do not root this robot.

Haha...

However i found many ways to root that CPU Model ( Snapdragon 400 )

Please look up how to root Snapdragon 400 CPU...

KingRoot Application will work...